# Greyed-out "waiting" page in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, user-input, wait

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Div as modal - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502435/div-as-modal-javascript)

Is there a way to somehow lock a page in Javascript until a function call is complete?  What I have in mind is like a semi-transparent grey cover that prevents any other user actions such as mouse-overs or button clicks until the current request is done processing.  The look-and-feel doesn't matter quite as much as the functionality, though.

I haven't been able to find anything that does this.  Most "solutions" to this problem simply say to wait to load the other HTML elements until you're done with whatever processing you're performing, but in this particular circumstance, all the options are *already present* on the screen.  I want to be able to prevent the user from performing another action from the page until the current request is complete.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what that is.  I'm fairly new to Javascript.

Comment: Some StackOverflow Questions: [div as modal in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502435/div-as-modal-javascript), [show html in a modal window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035334/show-html-markup-in-modal-window), [modal window over all screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392393/modal-window-how-to-over-all-screen)

Comment: @Chad Yes, I was in the process of looking it up.  Haha.  No, that's not quite what I mean.  The greyed-out portion *behind* that box is what I want.  I don't want the dialog in front of it.  Just the grey portion behind it that stays there until a function is done executing.

Comment: That is what makes the box a *modal* popup, as opposed to a regular popup. All of those links have the code necessary. All you need is some CSS and some show/hide in JS. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r77K8/1/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tend to use a simple `div` and some `javascript` to do this sort of thing.

So for example, in your page create a `div`, which will function as your grey-out.

```
      <div id="blackout" style='background-image:url(someSemiTransparent.png); display:none;"></div>
```

Then style it like so:

```
      #blackout {
      width:100%;
      height:100%; /* make sure you have set parents to a height of 100% too*/
      position: absolute;
      left:0; top:0;
      z-index:10 /*just to make sure its on top*/}
```

Then when your process is about to begin you can call (to show it):

```
      document.getElementById('blackout').style.display = 'block';
```

And once its done you can hide it again by:

```
      document.getElementById('blackout').style.display = 'none';
```

When you do show it, you may want to set the `overflow` of your `body` to `hidden`, then back to `auto` too, this will prevent the user scrolling and only seeing partial blackout.

Now I normally use `jquery` for the `show` and `hide` though am pretty sure the `javascript` above is correct..

Update:

To keep everything much tidier, as Chad mentions, you're better off putting all styling into CSS. I.E.

```
  #blackout {
     width:100%;
     height:100%; /* make sure you have set parents to a height of 100% too*/
     position: absolute;
     left:0; top:0;
     z-index:10 /*just to make sure its on top*/
     background-image:url(someSemiTransparent.png); 
     display:none;}
```

and remove the style from the `DIV`. I.E

```
      <div id="blackout"></div>
```

Comment: I can't +1 this until you move the inline styles of that div to the CSS :)

Comment: Updated :) Must have had a lazy-head on me :)

Comment: @Darren how can i set `overflow of your body to hidden` as you mentioned above? sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: That's ok @AsshO.Le - You could put a jquery command `$("body").css("overflow","hidden");` when you want it to hide any overflow, and then `$("body").css("overflow", "auto");` when you want it to revert.

Answer (score 8):

Use a

```
<div style="position:fixed;
            z-index: 2; /* above everything else */
            top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
"> <!-- possibly some loading-animation and/or explanation --> </div>
```

and add/remove it or show/hide it when you are processing.

Comment: Better than the selected option, the selected option uses an image file which is inferior to not needing to have one linked.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive elements have a "disabled" attribute which you can set to "disabled" to prevent them from emitting events.

You can position it to "disabled" before your processing, and position them back to "" to re-enable them at the end of your process.

I would recommend using jQuery to easily select the interesting element, keeping the selector result in memory during the process to use it to re-enable the elements after the process.

That being done, you can add pretty UI elements like a glass pane to emphasize the face that your screen is disabled.

Comment: That could be a LOT of elements to update if the page is complex.

Comment: Once you add the overlay, you don't need to disable anything. Blurring it, however, is worth considering.

Comment: Not that much, even in very large forms, you don't have hundreds of ***interactive*** elements. And you have to do it anyways, because a glasspane doesn't prevent hitting tab and using the controls with the keyboard

Comment: @JanDvorak the overlay doesn't block keyboard interaction. You - even accidentally - use use the tab key to cycle through active elements, which can lead to strange behaviors if the user is a monkey.