# How to check the internet connectivity?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-frontend

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(!isOnline && navigator.onLine){
        isOnline = true;
        console.log("Back online!");
    }
    else if(isOnline && !navigator.onLine){
        isOnline = false;
        console.log("Lost connection!");
}}, 100);
```

Is it possible to subscribe to data from 'navigator.online'?

The above method seems to be working fine in developer options, when comes to real-time it only checks whether my device is connected to a network or not.

What I want is how to check the status of the internet connectivity.

Comment: not an ideal solution - but it's safe to ask dns. If dns answers, you are connected https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/dns/resolve

Comment: or have look at this one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927071/check-web-app-is-online-or-offline)