# Check internet connection in web using Angular 4

Tags: angular, web

I am using Angular 4 for my application development. I need to check If the network connection is available for its have any Connection issue using Angular for. Is it possible with Angular 4.

I checked with `https://github.com/HubSpot/offline` . I think this will not work for angular 4. Any one please suggest. Is this possible to use offlinejs for Angular 4 or any other alternatives?

Thanks
Sarath C M

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether user has internet connection or not in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571231/how-to-check-whether-user-has-internet-connection-or-not-in-angular2)

Answer (score 80):

We don't need any libraries for this however `public onlineOffline: boolean = navigator.onLine;` will do the trick but this is just a one time check. We need to treat this value as an observable so whenever the online status change we are updated. For this rxjs will help.

Import these

```
import { Observable, Observer, fromEvent, merge } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Add this method

```
  createOnline$() {
    return merge<boolean>(
      fromEvent(window, 'offline').pipe(map(() => false)),
      fromEvent(window, 'online').pipe(map(() => true)),
      new Observable((sub: Observer<boolean>) => {
        sub.next(navigator.onLine);
        sub.complete();
      }));
  }
```

Subscribe to this event from your constructur or ngOnInit

```
this.createOnline$().subscribe(isOnline => console.log(isOnline));
```

*Note: Im using **Angular 8.1** and **rxjs 6.5.2***

Comment: nice solution! love it!

Comment: Working fine in **Angular 8.2.14** and **rxjs 6.5.3**

Comment: I love you! now i know how to make any var obseravle thanks bro

Comment: @tercou1 I am still using it even in angular 11

Comment: gives error for Angular9.1.12 and rxjs6.6.0 error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable<boolean>'.

Comment: if fromEvent dont exist in Modul, use =>  npm install --save rxjs-compat <= will be help.

Comment: This worked on Angular 14 and rxjs 7! However, I needed to delete the ````boolean```` as a return type of merge.

Comment: Also, @DilshanLiyanage can you explain your code (line by line)? It might help to understand what exactly happens under the hood.

Comment: This is a simple yet top tier implementation. +1. Explaining it more however might also help people understand the RxJS functions and operators used.

Answer (score 22):

You do not have to use any library for this, you can use  **`navigator`** global object like window. You can use in in angular4

```
public onlineOffline: boolean = navigator.onLine;
```

Comment: It will check in every page load is it right?. Without page refresh if the connection is gone i need to notify the user. And its reconnected that also need to inform. How can i make like that?

Comment: It always returns True

Comment: @Sajeetharan I am using the Same code as posted in the answer but it always returns true. Why?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale check my answer.

Comment: @DilshanLiyanage okay

Answer (score 4):

I created a class called `NetworkConnection` which checks status of network connection. Here is code sample

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';

export enum ConnectionStatusEnum {
  Online,
  Offline
}

export class NetworkConnection {

  public static status: ConnectionStatusEnum = ConnectionStatusEnum.Online;
  private static online$: Observable<string>;
  private static offline$: Observable<string>;

  public static init() {
    NetworkConnection.online$ = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'online');
    NetworkConnection.offline$ = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'offline');

    NetworkConnection.online$.subscribe(e => {
      console.log('Online');
      NetworkConnection.status = ConnectionStatusEnum.Online;
    });

    NetworkConnection.offline$.subscribe(e => {
      console.log('Offline');
      NetworkConnection.status = ConnectionStatusEnum.Offline;
    });
  }

  constructor() {
    NetworkConnection.init();
  }

}

new NetworkConnection();
```

And you can use it like

```
import { NetworkConnection, ConnectionStatusEnum } from './ConnectionStatus';
....
if(NetworkConnection.status == ConnectionStatusEnum.Offline) {
    // do something
}
....
```

Additionally, if you want to check connection to internet, you can periodically ping sites like `www.google.com` instead of `online/offline` events. OR combination of both the approaches.

Comment: Can you show an example of how pinging google would work to check internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

A solution for **RXJS 5.4.1** with *Angular 4* based on @Dilshan Liyanage answer.

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs/observable/fromEvent';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';

   /**
   * Return an observable with a boolean based on internet connection status
   */
  public checkInternetConnection(): Observable<boolean> {
    return Observable.merge<boolean>(
      fromEvent(window, 'online').map(() => true),
      fromEvent(window, 'offline').map(() => false),
      new Observable((sub: Observer<boolean>) => {
        sub.next(navigator.onLine);
        sub.complete();
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In angular 11 below code is worked for me. My requirement is if wifi connection is disabled from internet router, we should show some message to user.

```
::::::::::1 St STEP:(app.ts):::::::::::::::


import { Observable, fromEvent, merge, of } from 'rxjs';
import { mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({ / ... / })
export class MyComponent {
  online$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor() {
  this.online$ = merge(
   of(navigator.onLine),
   fromEvent(window, 'online').pipe(mapTo(true)),
   fromEvent(window, 'offline').pipe(mapTo(false))
  );
  }
}

:::::::::::2nd STEP:(app.html):::::::::::

<router-outlet cfBlockCopyPaste *ngIf="(online$ | async)"></router- 
 outlet>
 <div *ngIf="!(online$ | async)">
     <b>Please check your internet connection, then try again</b>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(navigator.onLine) {
     alert("You are Online")
    }
    else {
     alert("You are Offline")
    }
```

navigator.onLine --> returns true or false

Answer (score 1):

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {
        HttpRequest,
        HttpHandler,
        HttpEvent,
        HttpInterceptor
    } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class InternetInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        constructor() { }
    
        intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            // check to see if there's internet
            if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
                // if there is no internet, throw a HttpErrorResponse error
                // since an error is thrown, the function will terminate here
                return Observable.throw(new HttpErrorResponse({ error: 'Internet is required.' }));
    
            } else {
                // else return the normal request
                return next.handle(request);
            }
        }
    }


and put this in providers of app.module.ts
{
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: InternetInterceptorService,
        multi: true
    }
```

Comment: Please always describe what you are doing in your answer. It should be updated or removed. Read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before you provide more answers ^^

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

fromEvent(window, 'online').subscribe((resp: any) => {
   console.log(resp);
   console.log('online');
});

fromEvent(window, 'offline').subscribe((resp: any) => {
   console.log(resp);
   console.log('offline');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the required task, There is a npm package, ng-connection-service. Below is the complete code:

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ConnectionService } from 'ng-connection-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'internet-connection-check';
  status = 'ONLINE'; //initializing as online by default
  isConnected = true;

  constructor(private connectionService:ConnectionService){
    this.connectionService.monitor().subscribe(isConnected => {
      this.isConnected = isConnected;
      if(this.isConnected){
        this.status = "ONLINE";
      } else {
        this.status = "OFFLINE"
      }
      alert(this.status);
    });
  }
  ngOnInit(){

  }

}
```

Also you can find the working complete code over: [click here](https://jsonworld.com/demo/detail/65/angular2/how-to-check-internet-connection-in-angular-app)

Comment: There is open issue for [ng-connection-service](https://github.com/ultrasonicsoft/ng-connection-service/issues/23) as this library does not work on Angular 8 or above

Comment: The code written will only work in Angular 7 or its previous version.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to check if your browser is online/offline via `navigator.onLine`
The thing is, if `navigator.onLine` returns false, it means you are offline. But, returning true does not 100% make sure you are online. The reason is very simple and that is the implementation of the browser.

From the official documentation link [Navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)

> Browsers implement this property differently.
>
> In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local
>   area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions
>   return true. So while you can assume that the browser is offline when
>   it returns a false value, you cannot assume that a true value
>   necessarily means that the browser can access the internet. You could
>   be getting false positives, such as in cases where the computer is
>   running a virtualization software that has virtual ethernet adapters
>   that are always "connected." Therefore, if you really want to
>   determine the online status of the browser, you should develop
>   additional means for checking
>
> In Firefox and Internet Explorer, switching the browser to offline
>   mode sends a false value. Until Firefox 41, all other conditions
>   return a true value; testing actual behavior on Nightly 68 on Windows
>   shows that it only looks for LAN connection like Chrome and Safari
>   giving false positives.

Answer (score 0):

**navigator.online** won't give correct network status, In Chrome and Safari, if the browser is not able to connect to a local area network (LAN) or a router, it is offline; all other conditions return true. So while you can assume that the browser is offline when it returns a false value, you cannot assume that a true value necessarily means that the browser can access the internet.

Instead of using navigator.online, the best workaround is to call an API from Angular side. If there in no network, then the connection will fail and, thus, the error callback will be triggered.so you can write your own logic inside the error block to handle the offline functionality.

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to use any library for this, you can handle this by this few lines of code.

Add this below code into your comman error handler service file
file name errors-handlers-services.ts

```
if (string.includes(<<error message>>)) {
      window.location.reload();
 }
```

This code block is working for me. maybe this code snippet helps you!!

Answer (score -1):

Detecting internet connection status in Angular application

We can achieve desired feature using `window.ononline` and `window.onoffline` events.

You can install service via `npm` command:

```
npm i ng-connection-service
```

Subscribe to monitor() method to get push notification whenever internet connection status is changed

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ConnectionService } from 'ng-connection-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  status = 'ONLINE';
  isConnected = true;

  constructor(private connectionService: ConnectionService) {
    this.connectionService.monitor().subscribe(isConnected => {
      this.isConnected = isConnected;
      if (this.isConnected) {
        this.status = "ONLINE";
      }
      else {
        this.status = "OFFLINE";
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: this answer is already given above, how it is different from above one ?