# How to check internet connection in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, api, typescript, connection

My project work with API. I want to check internet when is disconnection and don't connection webservice. In this moment I want  to display alarm in web. Can you suggest me some idea, your experience please? Thnx

Comment: If you are disconnected you cannot connect to the webservice. So when your connection to the webservice fails you know you have no connection. Some code of how you connect to the webservice would be useful.

Comment: You could ping a random site. If you get a response then you're online, else you're not. Search for 'angular4 ping' there's several sources you can use.

Comment: i thing this question is dublicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46598777/check-internet-connection-in-web-using-angular-4)

Comment: check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51670162/842386