# Network detection in angular or http client proper error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, angular4-httpclient

I have two questions.

1. angular **httpclient get** method returns **unknown error** when I have lost my internet connection.
2. another question is when I tried `navigator.onLine` its always returning `true`.
   after that I used `addeventlistener('online')`, `addeventlistener('offline')` as well as `hostlistener` also
   these are not getting trigger hen I lost and found an internet connection.

If I am missing something please let me know

Comment: Have you tried using `observable` to handle this, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57069101/2012333

Comment: Yes I have tried this.  But it did not work for me.